# two form classes accessing a different class C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, oop

**- i have three classes:**

1. Main winform that is called when starting the program.
2. winform that is called when the 1st form is loaded (waiting for password).
3. Class for methods i use and has some variables.

When i access the **3rd** class via the **2nd**, and then i save some data on the variables of **3rd** it is saved and i can see it when i debug the prgram. the problem is when i try to access the variables of **3rd** again via the the **1st*, the data isn't saved (i think it is because of calling the **3rd** class ex: **3rd_Class class = new 3rd_class()**). is there anyway to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

**1st class code:**

```
public partial class form_parent : Form{
    
    private Methods methods = new Methods();
    private void form_parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form_dbPass dbpass = new form_dbPass();
        dbpass.ShowDialog();
        if (!dbpass.verified)
            Close();
        
        string txt = methods.DBpassword;
    }
}
```

---

**2nd class code:**

```
partial class form_dbPass : Form
{
    private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    
        Methods methods = new Methods();
        methods.DBpassword = "test";
    }
}
```

---

**3rd class code:**

```
public class Methods
{ 
   public string DBpassword = "";
    
   public void createDB(string password){

   ADODB.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as ADODB.Connection;
   if (con != null)
      con.Close();    
   DBpassword = password;
   }
}
```

Comment: When you say "form classes", do you mean WinForms?

Comment: yes i edited the post with some of my code to simplify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops i first didnt read it correctly, although i still dont understand how you create that object without an Constructor but neithertheless.

just creating an object of the class on both forms wont reference anything as they are 2 different objects. but thats a simple solution.

Make that object public in the second form..

```
public Methods methods = new Method();
```

and then simple reference the object either through the constructor(not needed public then) on create or just passing it..

in form_parent

```
Methods objToPass = new Method();
form_dbPass frm2 = new form_dbPass(objToPass); //obv set it in the 
//constructor then
frm2.Show()
```

or...

in form_dbPass..

```
public Methods method = null;
```

in form_parent

```
Methods objToPass = new Method();
form_dbPass frm2 = new form_dbPass();
frm2.Methods = objToPass;
```

done, that will reference it and they are the same **at that point**
if u want it to consitently update, you have to update it manually or through other ways.

I hope i could help you. Greets

Comment: We all start anywhere :) Was one of my biggest oofs in starting

Answer (score 0):

`private Methods methods` from the "1st class" and `Methods methods` from the "2nd" have no relation to each other.

Comment: i know i just want to know if there is a solve to this problem without changing much code because i will start from scratch if i couldn't